how to verify minting was successful before proceeding in solidity OZ?
here is my contract details below. remix is showing me that _exists is not found and setTransfer not found. you guys got any clue on this ? I want to verify the minting of a token actually was successful and then i will proceed to transfer the token to its destination address.
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract GarageSaleNFT is ERC721, Ownable {
    uint256 private _tokenIdCounter;

    // Define string constants
    string public constant TOKEN_NAME = "GarageSaleNFT";
    string public constant TOKEN_SYMBOL = "GSNFT";
    string public constant TOKEN_NOT_OWNED_BY_SENDER = "Token not owned by sender";

    constructor(address ownerAddress) ERC721(TOKEN_NAME, TOKEN_SYMBOL) Ownable(ownerAddress) {}

    function mint(address to) external onlyOwner {
        _tokenIdCounter++;
        _safeMint(to, _tokenIdCounter);
    }

    function burn(uint256 tokenId) external onlyOwner {
        _burn(tokenId);
    }

    function migrate(address from, address to, uint256[] memory tokenIds) external onlyOwner {
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < tokenIds.length; i++) {
            require(ownerOf(tokenIds[i]) == from, TOKEN_NOT_OWNED_BY_SENDER);
            _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenIds[i], "");
        }
    }


    function mintAndTransfer(address to) external onlyOwner {
    _tokenIdCounter++;
    uint256 tokenId = _tokenIdCounter;

    // Mint the token
    _safeMint(address(this), tokenId);

    // Check if the minting was successful
    require(_exists(tokenId), "Minting failed");

    // Transfer the minted token to the recipient
    safeTransfer(address(this), to, tokenId);
}

 // Function to allow safe transfer of tokens from one address to another
    function safeTransfer(address from, address to, uint256 tokenId) external onlyOwner {
        _safeTransfer(from, to, tokenId, "");
    }

    // Function to check if an address owns a specific token ID
    function tokenOwner(uint256 tokenId) external view returns (address) {
        return ownerOf(tokenId);
    }
}

i do understand that if _safeMint fails that transaction is reverted and no more code is run but how will the owner know the minting failed ? thats why i want to check if the token actually got minted.



_exists function doesn't exist anymore, it has been removed lately by OZ, the alternative to that would be:
require(_ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0), "Minting failed");

You have defined the safeTransfer function as an external function, which means the function can only be called from outside the contract. Either make it public (can be called from outside or inside the contract) or you can directly call the _safeTransfer function from the OZ contract.


